# Coinflip bot infinite loop

Tags: python, infinite-loop

I am trying to create an infinite loop for my coin flip bot so It will just keep pumping out results, as someone totally new to Python I am completely lost.  I have done some reading about looping and nothing is jumping out at me.

Thank you so much for any help.

```
from random import randint
import random
heads = 0
tails = 0
cointoss = 0

while True:
    coinresult = random.randint(1,2)
    cointoss +=1

    #end the loop if cointoss is greater than 100
    if cointoss > 101:
        break
    if coinresult == 1:
        heads +=1
        cointoss +=1
    elif coinresult == 2:
        tails +=1
        cointoss +=1

print("Heads came up", heads, "times")
print("Tails came up", tails, "times")
```

Comment: At the moment, you increment `cointoss` *twice* in each iteration, so you will only get half the number of results. It would be better to use `for _ in range(100):` than the `while True:` loop.

Answer (score 3):

Your exact code as of now is equivivalent to

```
import random

def coinflip(maxtosses=-1):
    tosses = 0

    while tosses != maxtosses:
        tosses += 1
        yield random.choice([True, False])

heads, tails = 0
for toss in coinflip(100):
    if toss:
        heads += 1
    else:
        tails += 1
```

If you really wish infinite loop - pass nothing or negative value as parameter to `coinflip` function. This way, however, you won't be able to ever stop it (well, unless you interrupt in with Ctrl+C or something like that).

`coinflip` is a [generator expression](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), so you can do some tricks to interrupt infinite loop depending on some condition.

Comment: "cointoss is a generator expression" I think you meant `coinflip`. Apart from that, +1`

Comment: @tobias_k, obvious typo, thanks. Also, I think nobody would mind if you just edit such kind of errors in their answers :)

Answer (score 2):

J0HN's answer is legit, but I thought I'd slightly modify your own answer to show you how to do something similar.  You weren't very clear as to what exactly the problem was with your own code, but this change makes it actually "infinite" until you tell it to stop.  I commented out the lines that are no longer needed.

```
#from random import randint
import random
heads = 0
tails = 0
#cointoss = 0

print("hit Ctrl-C to stop the inifinite loop!")
try:
    while True:
        coinresult = random.randint(1,2)
        #cointoss +=1

        #end the loop if cointoss is greater than 100
        #if cointoss > 101:
        #    break
        if coinresult == 1:
            heads +=1
        #    cointoss +=1
        elif coinresult == 2:
            tails +=1
        #    cointoss +=1
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Heads came up", heads, "times")
    print("Tails came up", tails, "times")
```

Also, you don't need to do both `from random import randint` and also `import random`.  If you do the first one, then you can call `randint(1,2)` directly (the import statement declares that it can find randint in the random library).  If you do the second import then you have to call `randint` as a child of `random`, so `random.randint(1,2)`.